# Reading Shopify shop metafields with Django/Python: Discrepancy between AJAX call and backend view behavior

Tags: python, django, shopify, shopify-app

Getting the list of shop metaifleds works great if running on the server in a simple Django view:

```
def my_view(request):
    with request.user.session:
        shop = shopify.Shop().current()
        print(shop.metafields())
        # returns [(metafield(1232543), metafields(143534534), etc]
```

However, if I do something like this (don't panic, I'm just experimenting) in an AJAX handler, it returns an empty array.

```
@csrf_exempt
def proxy_request(request):
    site = "my-store.myshopify.com"
    shop_user = AuthAppShopUser.objects.get(myshopify_domain=site)
    user = auth.authenticate(request=request, myshopify_domain=site, token=shop_user.token)
    if user:
        auth.login(request, user)

        with request.user.session:
            shop = shopify.Shop().current()
            print(shop.metafields())   # returns []
```

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: First thing to validate is that you even have a valid shop session. If the shop object is empty, there are for sure no metafields for you, so start one level high. If you have no shop, then it is likely you have not successfully authenticated. So start checking out your authorization code. Eventually, you'll see where you screwed up. Normal debugging right.

Comment: You didn't define `site` in `shop_user = AuthAppShopUser.objects.get(myshopify_domain=site)`

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the question - please assume `site` is valid and defined.

Comment: @DavidLazar The shop object is valid